# Correctly use reusable UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I am trying to build an application, that uses reusable UITableViewCells. In my 1st UITableView everything worked right, but now, in my 2nd table I can't use the reusable UITableViewCell, the Cell just stays blank. Here are my configurations:

1; I created a UITableViewCell class

2; I linked the UITableViewCell to the costume UITableViewClass I created in step one

3; I set the "Reuse identifier" to `Cell1`

4; I added some content to the reusable UITableViewCell

5; I imported the costume UITableViewCell class to my UIViewController

6; I added the standard UITableView code to my UIViewController: `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`, `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;`,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *costumeCell1 = @"Cell1";

    AppDetailCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:costumeCell1];

    if (!cell1) {
        cell1 = [[AppDetailCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:costumeCell1];
    }

    cell1.appIconImageView.image = self.appIcon;
    cell1.detailAppNameTextView.text = self.detailAppName;
    cell1.developerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@", self.appDeveloper];

    return cell1;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

7; I build the project, but I only can find a blank UITableView

I made it the same way as I have done it with the other reusable TableViewCell in an other UIViewController.

Anyone have an idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Are your `UITableViewDataSource` methods actually being called?  (NSLog)

Comment: No, they weren't called, I checked my code again, and found out, that I forgot to set the delegate to self, silly me!!